# How can I escape a hook?

Tags: dead-by-daylight

After playing a few rounds as a survivor in *Dead by Daylight*, I've learned that I am terrible at actually surviving. This carries over into my time as the killer, as well, since I'm equally bad at killing those same survivors.

My main issue seems to be the sacrificial hook. When I'm a survivor, I can't seem to escape from the hook. When I'm the killer, the survivors *always* escape my hook. I'm baffled, because escaping the hook *seems* like it's completely RNG. What am I missing? How does one escape the hook?

Comment: Since this was bumped already: The best way to escape a hook is to have one of your teammates unhook you.  The only real exception to this is if you have the perk Deliverance which, if you've already unhooked someone else, gives you 100% chance to unhook yourself the first time you're hooked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no definite guarantee way to escape the hook. It is purely RNG in the beginning part of the game. When it says "Attempt to escape" it is a 4% chance that you can escape. If you try this and fail then the dying process speeds up and you go into the struggling space phase. When you enter the struggle phase your dying process will slow down and your fellow survivors can help you.

Additionally, some perks give you increased luck or other advantages to escaping the hook that stack on top of the base 4% chance to succeed escaping the hook.

This above part is from pure experience. However on the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_by_Daylight) it says that :

The first time a survivor is hooked they enter the normal phase. In this phase the player has a low chance of escaping. If the player escapes and is hooked a second time they will enter the struggle phase, in which the player has to resist the entity trying to stab him/ her by pressing the spacebar multiple times. If the player is hooked a third time they will die instantly.

After anymore googling I could not find any more information. I hope this helps you!

Comment: "...you go into the struggling space phase. If you don't struggle then your dying process will slow down and your fellow survivors can help you.". What's the point of struggling then?

Comment: Thank you for noticing that mistake :P I am suprised others haven't picked up on that yet!

Comment: @user598527 from my experience if you dont't struggle you will be killed much before you have no life left. However once you reached the struggeling phase and going to be hooked again you die instantly. You may note that you can be unhooked even if not struggeling

Comment: Yes @Clayn they were pointing out a mistake i made in the original post I made, I translated some information incorrectly. Struggling WILL slow down the life draining process.

Comment: I think it should be mentioned that you can try to escape up to 3 times on the hook, each attempt removing 33% of the time left in the first phase. It should also be mentioned that trying to escape with less than 33% of the time left in the first phase will give you less time in the struggle phase and puts you into the struggle phase.

Comment: Sabotaged hooks let people get off too right?